# How to show seconds on the Windows 10 tray clock

Tags: taskbar, windows-10

How do I show seconds on the Windows tray clock? I've tried the advanced options in the control panel, but I'm not sure how do I do it. Is it like `hh:mm:ss` or is it something else?

Comment: The only way is by using 3rd party apps and this should be discouraged because anything which supports this must also redraw that area of the task bar every second. This lowers performance, the best way is to click on it if you want to watch seconds tick by.

Comment: I thought I needed to type a specific option like 
`hh:mm:ss` or something like that, and that's it?
The 3rd party app I was using doesn't have support for Windows 10.

Comment: The dialog you would type that into specifically says that `s` doesn't work for `short time formats` and that is what is used by the clock. I highly doubt there is even a registry setting for using `long time format` because of the aforementioned refresh difference. I don't know every option for every version of Windows and I definitely don't know every option in the registry for every version of Windows. Still, I highly doubt that the option exists without a third party app. Don't worry though, there are plenty which do this, just look for them.

Comment: 3rd party app I was using has no support for Windows 10, got any alternatives?

Comment: Sorry, I use 7 and I don't like things which need to write over system files to install. If I was going to do this I'd just grab a gadget that does it (and it'd be one of the stock gadgets since those were discontinued).

Comment: There are apps that restore default gadgets exe file to Windows 8 & 10
But installing all of this just for two numbers to show up on the tray clock? Hell no!

Comment: This [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031010-00/?p=42203/) is relevant and explains why the seconds counter was removed from the clock.

Answer (score 35):

*Source : [How to Show Seconds in Taskbar Clock in Windows 10?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/show-seconds-taskbar-clock-showsecondsinsystemclock/)

1. Start Regedit.exe and go to the following registry branch:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

2. Create a REG_DWORD value named ShowSecondsInSystemClock
3. Set its value data to 1.
4. Logoff and login back.

This adds seconds to the tray clock.

Works in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (v1607) and higher.

Comment: An easy trick. Works great without any trouble.

Comment: Instead of logging off and on again, you can also restart Explorer.exe. Just use the Task Manager, find explorer.exe and click 'Restart'.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Instead of doing that (the finding can take a while), press Windows + R. Then Ctrl + Shift + Right Click on the taskbar, click "Exit Explorer", type "explorer" into the Run… box and click Ok.

Answer (score 4):

7+ Taskbar Tweaker Beta can enable seconds on the standard Taskbar clock.

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

Comment: Could you possibly expand your answer to explain why you recommend this particular software over the other ones suggested?

Comment: 7+TT has loads of features which make the taskbar much more useful. I'm not a "tweaker" and try to keep bloat on my PC to the absolute minimum, but I wouldn't be without it. it's not just for visual toys; these are real producivity tweaks for people who use a lot of windows at the same time.

Comment: @Burgi, Like Andy said, it contains more than just tweaking the clock, but the tweak is just that, it tweaks the clock that is already there to show seconds, without replacing the clock like the other apps do. 

One downside is, as it does tweak the OS's clock, seconds are displayed on Windows 10's lockscreen but they don't update.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively , Since windows 10 supports the apps , you should be able to find digital clock app in windows store and install it.

[Windows 10 Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps-and-games#)

[App Store Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDFXN8rqqLo)

Or

[How to enable gadgets on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieW27hIS9Us)

You can enable gadgets for windows 10 which is not recommended anymore by  Microsoft and add digital clock to your desktop.

Windows 10 Gadgets Download link : http://goo.gl/sXSAUw

OR

Go to github using the link below , Download the zip file at the bottom of the page T-clock.zip like in the shared below.  Unzip it , after unzipping it ,  you will have a folder then open  the folder , you will see clock.exe double click on it .  if your operating system 64 bit then double click on clock64.exe , then you should be able to see clock.

[Git Hub](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases/tag/v2.3.2%23151-beta)

[image]

[image]

[image]

OR

Install free desktop clock , it is compatible with windows 8 most probably will work with windows 10 [FREE DESKTOP CLOCK](http://drive-software.com/freedesktopclock.html)

Comment: That's an app, not for the tray clock, like I wanted!

Comment: @Excel-Awesome:  "3rd party app I was using has no support for Windows 10, got any alternatives? " -- Seems like this is responsive to your comment, at least.

Comment: you may use github solution above , at least try it , most probably will work

Answer (score 0):

Usually I prefer solutions that don't require software installation but in this case I have to make an exception:

If 3rd party software is an option, I can definitely recommend using [T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases/). Its lightweight, freeware, opensource, portable and has been around since Windows XP. This is my current setting (including seconds and week numbers):

[image]

Although it's not part of the original question/requirement I like to emphasis that it has many, many, many other very practical additional features like showing week numbers, a custom calendar or even launching custom applications etc. Almost every aspect including it's GUI behaviour can be customized so the "wasted" space to "just show the clock" on the task bar becomes very productive.

I have been using it with WinXP for years but only recently found out that there is a new version for Windows 10 and had to install it right away.

I'm not affiliated with T-Clock in any way, just big fan since it's such a good tool.