# Seconds in Windows 10 clock - the answer may have changed

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, service-pack

Update: I was looking under wrong key. It's not `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`, it's `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`. I was missing the "Software" part.

This is a possible duplicate of [How to show seconds on the Windows 10 tray clock](https://superuser.com/questions/950283/how-to-show-seconds-on-the-windows-10-tray-clock?newreg=b27cb0136992412c81fe0febb2e9a154)  .

However, as of 3/16/2020, the latest update to Windows 10 does not have "Advanced" under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`.

[Regedit screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoHBi.png)

What is the solution now? Should we add the Advanced key?

Answer (score 2):

From [How-To Geeks:](https://www.howtogeek.com/325096/how-to-make-windows-10s-taskbar-clock-display-seconds/)

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `rege`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and confirm in the UAC dialog to get *Regedit*.
- Go to the following location (*not* that shown in the question), by copying the text and pasting into the location bar:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` .
- If the key, `ShowSecondsInSystemClock`, does not exist, right-click in the right pane and create a new DWORD with that name.
- Set the value of `ShowSecondsInSystemClock` to `1` to make seconds show, or to `0` to hide them.
  [image: Show Seconds in Windows Clock]

Comment: The entire folder, "Advanced", does not exist now. Should it be added?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct location? *Not* "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Microsoft\..." but "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\..."?

Comment: This is it. Thank you! Not sure if it should be closed as typographical error or kept as duplicate...